# Does anyone know a dataset to test the delta lake/apache iceberg?

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, delta-lake

I'm looking for an example dataset (or several) to test Delta Lake and Apache Iceberg, but I couldn't find any.

I want to test the MERGE function of both and compare, but a small example is not possible to measure performance and define which one is better.

I would like a dataset with primary keys that starts with the first version of the table, and with multiple datasets (small or large) with the changes, that way I could test MERGE.

If anyone can help me, I appreciate it in advance.